# Why aren't the Curie Temperature of Iron, Cobalt and Nickel periodic?

Tags: electromagnetism, metals

The Curie Temperature of iron, cobalt and nickel are respectively 1043 1400 627 degree Celsius.

But, the why doesn't three metals show periodicity about Curie Temperature? I have a thought that as Iron, Cobalt and Nickel have respectively 4,3,2 unpaired electrons, they should follow a decreasing trend; as from Iron to Nickel it would require more energy or more temperature to create complete chaos from more number of parallel aligned magnetic dipole having electrons than for lower number of parallel laid magnetic dipole electrons.

What is going on?

Comment: One needs to look deeper than just the 'unpaired' electrons. The relevant question is what the band structure looks like.

Comment: Can you cite me any research related to this?

Comment: Well, how is your solid star physics and band theory?

Comment: Know nothing about it. Average 12th grader.

Comment: @Jon Custer I think I can do it now. I have read some solid state physics like Fermi level, Energy level in Crystalline solid, occupancy probability, density of states etc.

Can you give me some resource where I can learn Curie Temperature deeply and answer my query?